# IF-IF-Else doesn't work as I need and want

Tags: c#

I need to know how I could handle my problem in a efficient and smart way:

I want an error-handling for user's input; I have 2 fields `CustomerID` and `Company`:

```
if (customerIDExists)
{
    errorMessage = "...";
}
if (companyInvalid)
{
    errorMessage = "...";
}
else
{
    // Add user to DB
}
```

There could be 3 errors:

1. CustomerID already exists
2. Company has an invalid name
3. CustomerID AND Company is invalid at the same time

With the example above the else is for the last if (companyInvalid). How can I deal with the else that this only executes when the 1 and 2 if doesn't match?

Else if is not right because I have to check all opportunities.

Comment: If(customerIDExists && companyInvalid) { //error error} else { //add to DB}

Comment: if(customerIDExists)
{
  errorMessage = "...";
} else {
if(companyInvalid)
{
 errorMessage = "...";
}
else
{
  // Add user to DB
} }

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could make it very explicit:

```
if (customerIDExists)
{
    ...
}
if (companyInvalid)
{
    ...
}

if (!customerIDExists && !companyInvalid)
{
    // Add user to DB
}
```

Or just use the fact that you haven't got an error message:

```
string errorMessage = null;
if (customerIDExists)
{
    errorMessage = ...;
}
if (companyInvalid)
{
    errorMessage = ...; // Don't forget it could already be non-null!
}

if (errorMessage == null) 
{
    // No error message, so we must be fine
    // Add user to DB
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your problem the else will fire if customerIDExists is true.

Try this

```
if(customerIDExists)
{
  errorMessage = "...";
}
else if(companyInvalid)
{
 errorMessage = "...";
}
else
{
  // Add user to DB
}
```

I've added an else if to the second condition. Now your application will check if the customerIDExists, if it doesn't it will check if the companyInvalid if it doesn't it will add the user to the database.

Now, what happens if both of these are incorrect? You'll only present on error message to your user, this will be annoying when they fix that issue and discover they have another you didn't tell them about! My suggestion would be to use a list of errors, if there aren't any then save to the database:

```
var errors = new List<string>();
if(customerIDExists)
{
  errors.Add("Customer exists");
}
if(companyInvalid)
{
  errors.Add("Company invalid");
}

if(!errors.Any())
{
  // Add user to DB
}
return errors;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable:

```
bool isValid = true;

if(customerIDExists)
{
    errorMessage = "...";
    isValid = false;
}

if(companyInvalid)
{
    errorMessage = "...";
    isValid = false;
}

if(isValid)
{
    // Add user to DB
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try old technique:

```
do {
    if(customerIDExists)
    {
        errorMessage = "...";
        break;
    }
    if(companyInvalid)
    {
        errorMessage = "...";
        break;
    }
    // All is ok.
} while (false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show all messages and don't break the proof after first error, you could use something like this:

```
List<string> errorMessages = new List<string>();
        if (customerIDExists)
        {
            errorMessages.Add("...");
        }
        if (companyInvalid)
        {
            errorMessages.Add("...");
        }

        if (errorMessages.Count == 0) //Valid
        {

        }
        else //Invalid
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you'd want to report **all** errors, not just the first that's encountered.

```
var errors = new List<string>();

if (customerIDExists)
{
    errors.Add("customer id exists");
}

if (companyInvalid)
{
    errors.Add("company is invalid");
}

if(errors.Any())
{
    // display all error messages
}
else
{
    // Add user to DB
}
```